# c++ 2dimensional pointer class array error (with openframeworks)

Tags: c++, class, multidimensional-array, openframeworks

i am trying to create a 2 dimensional pointer class array. Because i need a grid of class objects. 
Right now i'm getting an error that says:

testApp.cpp|53|error: no match for 'operator[]' in '((testApp*)this)->testApp::myCell[i]'|

```
// this is cell.h
class Cell
{


public:
    int x;
};
```

.

```
// this is testApp.h

class testApp : public ofBaseApp{
public:

    int width;
    int height;
    int Grid;
    int space;
    float wWidth;
    float wHeight;
    Cell myCell;


    void setup();
    void update();
    void draw();
};
```

.'
    // and this is testapp.cpp
    // this is where the error is

```
 void testApp::setup(){


Cell *myCell[5][5];
myCell[1][0]->x =2;
myCell[2][0]->x =1;
myCell[3][0]->x =23;
myCell[4][0]->x =4;
myCell[5][0]->x =7;
myCell[0][0]->x =4;



}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::draw(){

ofSetColor(255,255,0);
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    int q = myCell[i][0]->x;     // i get the error here. 
    ofCircle(20*q,20*q,50);
}
}
```

I don't understand why there is a problem with adressing the myCell pointer and the x parameter.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a special reason to use `Cell`, which only exposes an `int x` publicly instead of directly using `int` for `myCell`?

Comment: Also note, that your `myCell` array in setup is not initialized, meaning that the pointers in this array are invalid and dereferencing them will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: right now `int x` is a test. later on i need to draw various shapes based on several variables of `myCell`

Comment: That might justify the use of `Cell`, but let me ask why you use a pointer array. It just adds unnecessary complexity and hence increases the risk of errors.

Answer (score 2):

You have two objects named `myCell`. The first is a member of `testApp` with type `Cell`:

```
class testApp : public ofBaseApp {
  public:
    // ...
    Cell myCell;
    // ...
}
```

The other object named `myCell` is created in your `testApp::setup()` function and is of type `array of 5 array of 5 pointer to Cell`.

```
void testApp::setup() {
    Cell *myCell[5][5]; // This hides the previous myCell
    // ...
}
```

Within the `setup()` function, you are hiding the member `myCell`. When the function ends, the array version of `myCell` goes out of scope and doesn't exist any more. So first things first, you want to fix the definition of the member `myCell`:

```
class testApp : public ofBaseApp {
  public:
    // ...
    Cell* myCell[5][5];
    // ...
}
```

And remove the definition of `myCell` in `setup()`:

```
void testApp::setup() {
    // ...
}
```

You now have only one object called `myCell` which is a 2D array of pointers to `myCell`. But now we have another problem to solve. You have this array of pointers but they aren't currently pointing anywhere - they're *uninitialized*. You can't just try to do `myCell[1][0]->x` because there is no `Cell` object being pointed to at index `[1][0]`.

One way to get around this is to loop through the entire array, using `new` to dynamically allocate space for all the `Cell`s. You would do this as follows:

```
void testApp::setup() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            myCell[i][j] = new Cell();
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

However, a much better method is to not use dynamic allocation (`new`) at all. If you simply define `myCell` to be an array of `Cells`, rather than an array of pointers to `Cell`, the `Cell`s will be allocated on the stack automatically. This involves changing the member definition to:

```
class testApp : public ofBaseApp {
  public:
    // ...
    Cell myCell[5][5];
    // ...
}
```

Now when your `testApp` instance is created, the array will be allocated automatically. Now you can set up the contents of the array as follows:

```
void testApp::setup() {
    myCell[1][0].x = 2;
    myCell[2][0].x = 1;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this thorough explanation. I will stick to the array of Cells instead of the pointer array. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to refer to `myCell` from `testApp::setup()` in `testApp::draw()`, but you only can access the member `testApp::myCell` there, which is of type `Cell` and therefore does not support the operations you want.

**Edit**

One possible source of the crash you are mentioning could be your `setup()` function.
You are using unitialized pointers there. With the change you mentioned in your comment you also should change your code in setup to:

```
void testApp::setup(){
  //remove the next line to not shadow the member declaration
  //Cell *myCell[5][5];
  //replace -> by . as you are not handling pointers anymore
  myCell[1][0].x =2;
  myCell[2][0].x =1;
  myCell[3][0].x =23;
  myCell[4][0].x =4;
  myCell[5][0].x =7;
  myCell[0][0].x =4;
}
```

Comment: ok, well i seem to get past the error when i put 'Cell myCell[5][5];' in testapp.h. But then when i run it, it stops after a while with no result saying, application stopped working.

Comment: You should try to debug your program to see were it stopped and why, but probably it is because of an access violation.

Comment: may be you didn't allocated memory to the pointers... 
In Cell *myCell[5][5]; each Cell* should have a memory allocated to it..

Comment: Well, your edit post did it for me. I am not handling pointers anymore now. If this is the best option then i'll stick with this. I am trying to still get an array with pointers but i keep getting 'application stopped working

Comment: @Bluefarmer I don't see why you want to stick to pointers. If there is a good reason for this then it might be the better option but I cannot judge if you do not tell me this reason.

Comment: I am currently trying to see if i really need the pointers. I'm trying to recreate this . [link](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/1/10/maze-generation-prim-s-algorithm)      I am fairly sure that i will need to use pointers sooner or later but am not sure whether i'll need them as a pointer array.

Comment: So basically you are trying to implement Prim's algorithm? I do not know what `myCell` represents regarding to this algorithm, but as it is a graph traversal algorithm there are two possibilities: Pointers (or iterators) and indices. The first should be used with lists, the second with arrays. I don't know your implementation but my guess is, that you can avoid Pointers most of the time.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I might need some pointers to some individual objects but i don't need a 2d pointer array. Well thank you this helped me tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `myCell` is only defined within the scope of `testApp::setup`. Therefore, you cannot access it within the scope of `testApp::draw`. Think of making it an attribute of your `testApp` class.

Comment: Ok, I currently have `Cell myCell` as an attribute in `testapp.h`. How can i initialize the pointer array in the `testapp` class and depict the size in `testapp::setup`?